# I am trying to create a method that calculates the averages of numbers in two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Marks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Marks r = new Marks();
    double[] finalArray = r.openFile();
    double[] finalArray2 = r.openFile2();


}
//ID's and first set of grades

private Scanner a;

public double[] openFile() {
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        a = new Scanner(new File("IR101.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (a.hasNextLine()) {
        list1.add(a.nextLine());

    }

    String[] arrayOne = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayOne);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOne));
    int size = arrayOne.length;
    double[] finalArray = new double[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        String word = arrayOne[j];
        String newWord = word.substring(6, 10);
        double grade = Double.parseDouble(newWord);
        finalArray[j] = grade;

    }return finalArray;



}
//ID's and second set of grades


private Scanner b;

public double[] openFile2() {
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        b = new Scanner(new File("IR102.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (b.hasNextLine()) {
        list2.add(b.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arrayTwo = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayTwo);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayTwo));
    int size = arrayTwo.length;
    double[] finalArray2 = new double[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        String word = arrayTwo[j];
        String newWord = word.substring(6, 10);
        double grade2 = Double.parseDouble(newWord);
        finalArray2[j] = grade2;
    }return finalArray2;

}



// ID's and names

private Scanner c;

public void openFile3() {
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        c = new Scanner(new File("IRStudents.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (c.hasNextLine()) {
        list3.add(c.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arrayThree = list3.toArray(new String[list3.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayThree);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayThree));
    int size = arrayThree.length;

    String[] names = new String[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        names[j] = arrayThree[j].substring(6);
    }
    String[] IDs = new String[size];
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        IDs[x] = arrayThree[x].substring(0,5);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(IDs));

}
public void calculateAvg() {


}

}
```

I am trying to access the numbers in finalArray and finalArray2 but I am not sure how to do this when I try to call on the two arrays it does not work I think it is to do with the scope of the arrays.So how do I make the two array accessible to the whole program.

Comment: `it does not work` is not a good way to describe the problem as it tells us almost nothing about the actual problem at hand. Please be as specific as possible and add as many details as you can describing what is wrong wrong.

Comment: Looks like you havent done much research before adding this question. But you are right about the scope. The way it is currently setup it wont work unless you pass the arrays to the functions. You will need to decide whether you want to pass and return or just change scope to static.

Comment: Where are you trying to access it and why? Can you provide an example of the implementation you are attempting? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the two arrays accessible to the whole program, declare them as static variables outside of the main method and initialize inside like seen here:

```
    public class Marks {
        static double[] finalArray;
        static double[] finalArray2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Marks r = new Marks();
        finalArray = r.openFile();
        finalArray2 = r.openFile2();
```

Comment: Please fix your indenting so it's clear what is at what level.

Answer (score 0):

While you could make the arrays visible to the whole class, it probably makes more sense to pass them to the method which should access them. So do something like this:

```
public void calculateAvg(double[] array1, double[] array2) {
    // ...
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Marks r = new Marks();
    double[] finalArray = r.openFile();
    double[] finalArray2 = r.openFile2();
    r.calculateAvg(finalArray, finalArray2);
}
```